# If else vs switch with stack logic

Tags: java, if-statement, stack, switch-statement

I'm learning about stacks by writing a program that validates bracket syntax. If I input `(Baller)` it should give me a positive result. If I have `(Baller()` it should give me a negative result. Essentially the application checks if the user has correctly used ( ) , { } and [].

- If I encounter a ( , { , or [ character I will add it to the
  character on the stack.
- If I encounter a ) } ] sign I will delete a character from the stack.
- If the text contains an odd number of parentheses or brackets are not
  contiguous ( for example, ( and ] is not continuous ) , an error
  message is printed.

So I have done this half in a if else statement but I was thinking that it should be easier to make it in a switch statement and also be a good learning experience.

So what I have done in the switch statement is this:

```
public class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        String str;
        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Text to parse: ");
        char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
        System.out.print(str);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for(char c : arr) {
            switch(c) {

            case '{':
                stack.Push(c);
                System.out.print(stack.firstNode.getData());
                break;
            case '(':
                stack.Push(c);
                System.out.print(stack.firstNode.getData());
                break;
            case '[':
                stack.Push(c);
                System.out.print(stack.firstNode.getData());
                break;

            case '}':
                c = (Character) stack.Peek(); //<-- Edited for @Jimmy
                if( c != '{') {
                    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
                }
            case ']':
                if( c != '[') {
                    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
                }   
            case ')':
                if( c != '(') {
                    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting a problem that if I just add a right side bracket it will just remove because I have a pop. I tried to make this in a if-else statement which will end in a if-statement like this:

```
if(first == '(' && (current == '}' || current == ']')) {
if first == '{' && (current == ']' || current == ')')) {
//and so on
```

How could I turn this into a switch case? Is this a bad idea?

What I know is there isn't really a problem on my left side bracket but there is on the right ones.

EDIT: HOW THE CODE LOOKS LIKE RIGHT NOW

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        String str;
        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Text to parse: ");
        char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
        System.out.print(str);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();


        for(char c : arr) {

            switch(c) {

            case '{':
                stack.Push(c);
                break;
            case '(':
                stack.Push(c);
                break;
            case '[':
                stack.Push(c);
                break;

            case '}':
                if(stack.isEmpty() || (Character) stack.Pop() != '{') {
                    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
                }
                break;
            case ']':
                if(stack.isEmpty() || (Character) stack.Pop() != '[') {
                    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
                }
                break;
            case ')':
                if(stack.isEmpty() || (Character) stack.Pop() != '(') {
                    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
                }
                break;
            }
        } if(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use peek(), that will just let you see the last contents of the stack. If there is not error , then you can call pop() otherwise don't call pop and it won't be removed.

Comment: @Jimmy Could you do a exemple how it would work in a code? Otherwise where do you meant to change?

Comment: some thing like this  in your first removal case .i.e for case '}': `c = (Character) stack.Peek();
                if( c != '{') {
                    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
                }else stack.Pop(); `

Comment: @Jimmy Ok So I changed it to Peek() and got the same result. I changed in the edit to show you where it was edited.

Comment: I think the cleanest solution would be to avoid the fall-through and have an individual pop in each `case`.  Be aware of the case of an empty stack though.  Also, you should use `Stack<Character>` to get rid of the unsafe casts.

Comment: if closing character completes the last character on stack , you want to remove it from stack. If not, what are you expecting to do ? print error message and ignore the entry or print message and  remove the last entry from stack ?

Comment: Also for the extra closing character at the end, you can catch EmptyStackException() and handle it that way or check if stack isEmpty() before operating on stack.

Comment: Sorry for the late answers. Its happening so much. However I have wrote a bit more in a comment in this thread where it was created by Ben M. However My point is that I want it to give a me error if the bracklets doesnt are in a pair ect. ()) {[] and so on. It would give me a good result if I get it like () ([]) and yeah. I dont know what more I could add to this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!  It's good that you already have a workable solution and are trying to improve on it.

You can still use your switch statement, but you first need to verify that your stack isn't empty before you attempt to pop the next value.  In my implementation, I'm doing that check first by checking `stack.isEmpty()` and using a short-circuiting OR condition `||`.  Short-circuiting means that if the left side of an OR condition is true, then the right side will not even be evaluated.

This is the updated for loop.  I'm not sure which Stack class you're using, so mine is using `java.util.Stack`.

```
for(char c : arr) {

    switch(c) {

    case '{':
        stack.push(c);
        System.out.print(stack.peek());
        break;
    case '(':
        stack.push(c);
        System.out.print(stack.peek());
        break;
    case '[':
        stack.push(c);
        System.out.print(stack.peek());
        break;

    case '}':
        if(stack.isEmpty() || (Character) stack.pop() != '{') {
            System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
        }
        break;
    case ']':
        if(stack.isEmpty() || (Character) stack.pop() != '[') {
            System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
        }
        break;
    case ')':
        if(stack.isEmpty() || (Character) stack.pop() != '(') {
            System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:  I added missing `break;` statements.  Without these, the system will execute multiple `case:` conditions because it will 'fall through' to each one.

EDIT 2:  Zong Zheng Li makes a good point in their answer.  You should verify that there aren't any left over characters on the stack when you're done.  After your loop, you should have something like this:

```
if(!stack.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
}
```

EDIT 3:  Changed `stack.firstElement()` to `stack.peek()`.

Comment: This looks kinda amazed! However yeah.  I have created a own class where I have initialized by my own Push, Pop, Peek and Count methods. Which leave us that I don't have a isEmpty method. But I guess it almost the same as my Count() method since it returns elements in count. so if I do something change on it, could it help it?

Comment: @Thillofit123 Yep, you can use your Count() method if you want and just do an equality check with zero, e.g. `stack.Count() == 0`.  You should consider creating your own `isEmpty()` though, because it will make your code nicer to read (plus it's just generally a good practice to not repeat yourself).

Comment: public int Count() {
  
  return count;
 }
 
 public boolean isEmpty() {
  if(count == 0) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }
}

Could something like this be enough?

Comment: @Thrillofit123 That's almost perfect!  You can simplify it to just this: `public boolean isEmpty() { return count == 0; }`

Comment: Yay it worked! Wohooo! Really! I really appreciate your time here Ben. M and everyone else aswell! It works as far as I see. Now im going to try to make it more cooler but as I see now. everything is turning good! I Have no words to say!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Aside from checking whether specific characters match up, there are two cases where you need information about the stack itself:

1. When the number of brackets don't much up in an intermediate state. This happens when you try to pop when the stack is empty.
2. When there are orphaned brackets at the end of string. In this case the stack ends up non-empty.

To fix 1, you should check that the stack is not empty before popping:

```
case '}':
    if (stack.empty()) {
        System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
    }
    else {
        c = (Character) stack.Pop();
        if( c != '{') {
            System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
        }
    }
    break;
```

or equivalently,

```
case '}':
    if (stack.empty() || ((Character)stack.Pop()) != '{') {
        System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
    }
    break;
```

To fix 2, at end of your program, you should check the stack *is* empty. This catches the `(bal)ler)` case that has not been addressed.

```
if (!stack.empty()) 
    System.out.println("  Syntax ERROR");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you wanted to learn how to use the `switch` statement. There is a neat trick you can use, called *falling through*:

```
switch (c) {
    case '{':
    case '(':
    case '[':
        stack.Push(c);
        System.out.print(stack.firstNode.getData());
        break;

    case '}':
    case ']':
    case ')':
        if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != c) {
            System.out.println("Syntax ERROR");
        }
        break;
}
```

Also you can use pre-implemented [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class which is also [`generic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Comment: This looks very nice! I have created a own class where I have initialized by my own Push, Pop, Peek and Count methods. Which leave us that I don't have a isEmpty method. But I guess it almost the same as my Count() method since it returns elements in count. so if I do something change on it, could it help it? Because if I import the Java stack. It will give me a error for other things since I have created my own class with Pop, Push and so on.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use your own `Stack` class, unless you plan to publish your code as a library and use your own `Stack` in it's API. You can check if your stack is empty by `stack.count() == 0` so you don't need to create an `isEmpty()` method, that is entirely up to you.

Comment: Yay it worked! Wohooo! Really! I really appreciate your time here Kajacx and everyone else aswell! It works as far as I see. Now im going to try to make it more cooler but as I see now. everything is turning good! I Have no words to say!!!!